# Как убрать белый фон, при рисовании текста на Canvas через TextOut?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Доброго времени суток!

Делаю небольшой, целенаправленный, редактор картинок.
Вот так выглядит картинка в редакторе:
[image]
Поверх TImage, **лежат** простые TLabel, что-то вроде слоёв.

А вот как эти слои рисуются на картинку:
[image]
Рисование происходит вот так:

```
procedure TPrintForm.BuildPreview(aSsignTo: TImage);
    var
      Img: TBitmap;
      i: Integer;
    begin
      Img := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        Img.Assign(fSrcBitmap);
        for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
        begin
          Img.Canvas.Font := Items[i].Text.Font;
          Img.Canvas.TextOut(Items[i].Text.BoundsRect.TopLeft.X - Items[i].Text.Font.Size,
            Items[i].Text.BoundsRect.TopLeft.Y - Items[i].Text.Height -
            Items[i].Text.Font.Size, Items[i].Text.Caption);
        end;
        aSsignTo.Picture.Assign(Img);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(Img);
      end;
    end;
```

Как при TextOut избавляться от белого фона под текстом?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При создании объекта `Img` его фон будет залит цветом фона по умолчанию, т.е. белым.
Для начала залей его таким-же фоном, как у основной картинки:

```
Img.Canvas.Brush.Color:= clGray;
Img.Canvas.FillRect(0, 0, Img.Width, Img.Height);
```

Затем выставить прозрачность:

```
SetBkMode(Img.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Handle,TRANSPARENT);
```

Теперь текст будет выводиться на сером фоне.